# psql get a pair from single table

Tags: sql, postgresql

got a simple table of User with columns ID and NAME.

assuming there is an even number of users, I need a query to pair them, each user appearing one, on one side of the pair or another, and not appearing again.

Example

```
1 bob
2 joe
3 phil
4 ted
5 larry
6 jeremiah
```

becomes :

```
bob joe
phil ted
larry jeremiah
```

I have tried so far :

```
SELECT MIN(a.id) a, b.id b 
FROM users a 
JOIN users b 
on a.id < b.id 
GROUP by b.id;
```

but I only get :

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
```

Comment: `select a.name, b.name from users a join users b ON a.id %2 = 1 and b.id = a.id+1`

Comment: @wildplasser - You can post it as an answer. Good one.

Comment: here is the demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a232/3

Comment: thanks both of you, I was hammering my head with this for ages -_-.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.name
      , b.name
FROM users a
JOIN users b ON a.id % 2 = 1  -- a.id is odd
            AND b.id = a.id+1 -- b.id is odd+one (:=even)
  ;
```

---

Add the row_number() - trick if you want to bridge gaps in the id's:

```
WITH seq AS (
        SELECT u.name , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY u.id) AS seq
        FROM users u
        )
SELECT a.name
      , b.name
FROM seq a
JOIN seq b ON a.seq % 2 = 1     -- a.seq is odd
            AND b.seq = a.seq+1 -- b.seq is odd+one (:=even)
  ;
```

---

To also select the last single unpaired person, you can use a left join (and move the *odd* condition to a where clause)

```
-- DELETE FROM users where id = 1;

WITH seq AS (
        SELECT u.name , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY u.id) AS seq
        FROM users u
        )
SELECT a.name
      , b.name
FROM seq a
LEFT JOIN seq b ON b.seq = a.seq+1 -- b.seq is odd+one (:=even)
WHERE a.seq % 2 = 1                -- a.seq is odd
  ;
```

Comment: Works only if there are no gaps in the ids. GordonLinoff's thing with the row_number() even works if there are gaps.

Comment: oh, you mean if there's no id missing, yeah I just noticed, guess I'll give it to him then.

Comment: I was wandering, if I'd like to upgrade this, and how could I pair them based on a third column, called Points, so that users are paired with the other user with the closest Points amount? Even if this isn't possible, thanks a lot.

Comment: Just change the ordering in the window: `OVER (ORDER BY u.id) AS seq` -->> `OVER (ORDER BY u.points, u.id) AS seq`

Comment: that's great. out of curiosity, Gordons seems to even work with an odd amount of users, which yours ignores an aditional user. Was wandering if that could work here. (doesn't have to, just wanted to know how that could work.)

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this with conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when id % 2 = 1 then name end),
       max(case when id % 2 = 0 then name end)     
from users u
group by (id - 1) / 2;
```

In the event that you don't have sequential ids, then you can add them using `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then name end),
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then name end)     
from (select u.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum from users u) u
group by (seqnum - 1) / 2;
```

Comment: noticed the second one so went back here, since I can't guarantee sequential ids.

Comment: so, I keep getting Incorrect syntax near 'users'. when I try to run the second one...is it possible to provide an sqlfiddle?

Comment: Note: There is a `FROM` missing between `seqnum users u`